# Restrict Profile2 Profile Type on Role

Tags: 7, users

I would like to do a few things:

1. Limit the profile type a user has based on their role. When/if they change roles, their profile type would change and any fields that were the same are brought forward.
2. When accessing a user's profile page, the relevant profile type displays (one URL).
3. Allow users to display some of the fields in their core profile in the profile2 page that people see. (eg. birthday in core displayed as age in profile2 page).

Or am I thinking about this all wrong? Should I just think of profile types as different pages of the same profile that happen to have different fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can use permissions to assign profile(s) to roles.

about:

> When/if they change roles, their profile type would change and any
>   fields that were the same are brought forward.

Remember each profile form is independent, so what you want could be done with code.  Or you can use only one profile form and use the field permissions module to assign role(s) per field (even if this is the case, maybe you don't need profile2).

Using only profile 2 (and turning off profile2 page),  you would see your core profile fields and the profile2 fields together.